# Efficiency of declaring a pointer to a pointer in C++

Tags: c++, performance, pointers

This may sound like a petty problem but in a program I am creating, I have a recursive function, in which I declare a pointer to a pointer to a class 'QuadTree'.

i.e. :

```
void check_tree(QuadTree* p_qtree, Object* p_obj)
{
  if (!p_qtree->is_leaf())
  {
    QuadTree** children = p_qtree->get_children();  // <-- WHAT I'M REFERRING TO
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      check_tree(children[i], p_obj);
  }
  else
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Does declaring 'QuadTree**' inside the recursive function decrease the efficiency of the program because of the repeated calls to the function or are the effects negligible? Is it better to declare it outside the function like the following?

```
QuadTree** children;   // <-- MOVE DECLARATION TO HERE
void check_tree(QuadTree* p_qtree, Object* p_obj)
{
  if (!p_qtree->is_leaf())
  {
    children = p_qtree->get_children();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
      check_tree(children[i], p_obj);
  }
  else
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

My initial thought was that the effects of declaring the pointer to the pointer within the recursive function would be negligible since it only allocates memory for a pointer rather than an entire class, but I'm not so sure. Any feedback would be great.

Comment: Moving the var outside will generate a bug. See the explanation below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance wise, there would be no difference between allocating a stack of size n and a stack of size m (they both compiles to reading a register, adding a constant value, and storing the value back to the same register).

Memory-wise, by declaring the variable inside the function, each level of stack will use an extra 8 bytes (on 64-bit machine) or 4 bytes (on 32-bit machine). IMO, negligible. Also, the compiler might be able to optimize this away when this can be done safely.

Correctness-wise, allocating the memory outside makes your function non-reentrant. This can be a problem when you use multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

That behavior is called [*two-star programming*](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) and is generally considered bad.

You can easily get away with references instead (which are both "performant" and readable):

```
void check_tree(QuadTree& p_qtree, Object& p_obj) {
    if (!p_qtree.is_leaf()) {
        QuadTree& children = p_qtree.get_children();  // should return a reference to QuadTree
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            check_tree(children, p_obj);
    }
    // ...
}
```

As far as performance goes, each pointer is an extra level of indirection. But the way of compiler optimizations are infinite.

Comment: Certainly valid when c++ is available (as it is in this case), but this doesn't answer the posted question.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, declaring it outside will lead you to a bug: When `check_tree` is called recursively for the second time, the `children` var will be overwritten if there is a non-leaf inside another non-leaf.

```
check_tree
   children = something
   recursive check_tree when i=0
       children = overwritten with something
   recursive check_tree when i=1 -> has the incorrect "children".
```